# automatically updating the links of workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, vbscript

iam looking for a way to open .xlsb files in a folder one by one and then rename or update its links as .xlsb.

For example if "C:\FINAL ANSWER\edit.xlsb" file has links  as ='C:\FINAL ANSWER\MAIN VALUES.xlsx!L30' then the code

should be able to rename that link as ='C:\FINAL ANSWER\MAIN VALUES.xlsb!L30'.

Each folder has many workbooks with various sheets in it so the macro should be able to search in every workbook
and every sheets with the links .xlsx and replace it with .xlsb as explained above.

Thanks

Comment: You need to qualify more clearly what your requirement is - rename all `.xlsx` links to `.xlsb` or only if some part of the path matches.  You also say you want to do them "*one by one*" but also it should "*search every workbook and sheet*".  If you could show what you've tried so far it may be clearer.

Comment: I have a workbook at C:\FINAL ANSWER\FOLDER4\FOLDER3\DATA CAL2SECOND.xlsb that workbook has links such as ='C:\FINAL ANSWER\FOLDER4\FOLDER3\[DATA CALSECOND.xlsx]CALS VALUES'!EN64 in several sheets , the required solution is to convert.xlsx of   those links to .xlsb for example that above link after conversion should be  'C:\FINAL ANSWER\FOLDER4\FOLDER3\[DATA CALSECOND.xlsb]CALS VALUES'!EN64. I can do the same by using FIND AND REPLACE FUNCTION but it will take ages to convert links of each of the workbooks to .xlsb so a solution for several workbooks is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following into a Module and run the UpdateLinks macro. A directory dialogue box appears to select the directory on which to perform the Link Updates. Check your Immediate window for Errors and Stats. Please post back some of the output and Good Luck!

This may not be as time consuming to do manually as one might think. You do not need to edit every cell or even the Named Ranges list. Each unique file which is part of one or more external references is a single entry in the Links manager. Data [Tab] | Queries & Connections [Section] | Edit Links [Dialogue] | Change Source ... [Dialogue] allows you to modify each file being referenced. So even if a file is referenced in multiple cells and sheets and each of the references is to different sheet and range in the referenced file, one change updates all the references to the new file name or location (including a file extension modification).

```
Option Explicit
Private Const OpenFiles = "xlsb|xls|xlt|xlsx|xltx|xlsm|xltm" 'single ext is OK
Private Const OldExt = "xlsx"
Private Const NewExt = "xlsb"
Sub UpdateLinks()
    Dim directory, excelFiles() As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim app As Excel.Application
    Dim totalUpdates As Integer

    directory = getDirectory
    excelFiles = getExcelFiles(directory)
    If LBound(excelFiles) = 0 Then 'empty excel file list for directory
        MsgBox "Directory '" & directory & "' has no files of type *." _
            & Join(Split(OpenFiles, "|"), ", *.")
        End 'Exit Subroutine and Execution Call Stack
    End If '(Else)
    Debug.Print "DIRECTORY '" & directory & "' has " _
        & UBound(excelFiles) & " excel file(s)."
    Set app = New Excel.Application
    app.DisplayAlerts = False
    app.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable 'disable macros

    totalUpdates = 0
    Dim file As Variant
    For Each file In excelFiles
        Set wb = openWorkbook(app, directory & Application.PathSeparator & file)
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then
            totalUpdates = totalUpdates + updateExcelLinks(wb)
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next file
    app.Quit
    Debug.Print "COMPLETE: " & totalUpdates & " link(s) updated from '" _
        & OldExt & "' to '" & NewExt & "'."
End Sub
Function updateExcelLinks(ByRef wb As Workbook) As Integer
    updateExcelLinks = 0
    Dim links As Variant
    links = wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks) 'includes externally Named Ranges
    If IsEmpty(links) Then
        Debug.Print "No Excel links in '" & wb.Name & "'."
        Exit Function
    End If '(Else) Process Links
    Dim l As Variant
    For Each l In links
        If StrComp(OldExt, Right(l, Len(l) - InStrRev(l, "."))) = 0 Then
            wb.ChangeLink l, Left(l, InStrRev(l, ".")) & NewExt
            updateExcelLinks = updateExcelLinks + 1
        End If
    Next l 'xlExcelLinks iterator
    If updateExcelLinks = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No links with '" & OldExt & "' extensions in '" & wb.Name & "'."
    ElseIf wb.ReadOnly Then
        Debug.Print "ERROR, cannot save '" & wb.Name & "' (opened in another app). " _
            & updateExcelLinks & " link extension(s) NOT updated."
        updateExcelLinks = 0
        wb.Saved = True 'discard unsavable workbook changes
    Else
        wb.Save
        Debug.Print "Updated " & updateExcelLinks & " excel link extension(s) in '" & wb.Name & "'."
    End If
End Function
Function openWorkbook(ByRef app As Excel.Application, ByVal fileName As String) As Workbook
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    Set openWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0) '0 is do not update ext refs when opening
    If Not openWorkbook Is Nothing And openWorkbook.FileFormat <> xlCurrentPlatformText Then
        Exit Function 'Return valid workbook
    End If '(Else)
    'Not a valid Workbook
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "ERROR: Could not open excel workbook '" & fileName & "'. " _
            & vbCrLf & "Error #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Debug.Print "ERROR: Not a valid excel workbook '" & fileName _
             & "' (opened as a text file)."
    End If
    If Not openWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        openWorkbook.Close (False) 'False is don't save
        Set openWorkbook = Nothing
    End If
End Function
Function getExcelFiles(ByVal directory As String) As String()
    Dim f As String
    Dim fnames() As String
    ReDim fnames(0) 'testing has shown this is neither inefficient nor slow

    f = Dir(directory & Application.PathSeparator)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        If InStr("|" & OpenFiles & "|", "|" & Right(f, Len(f) - InStrRev(f, ".")) & "|") Then
            If LBound(fnames) = 0 Then
                ReDim fnames(1 To 1)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve fnames(1 To UBound(fnames) + 1) 'see redim fname comment above
            End If
            fnames(UBound(fnames)) = f
        End If
        f = Dir 'get next iterative file from the original Dir called with argument
    Loop
    getExcelFiles = fnames
End Function
Function getDirectory() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = " Link Updater - Select Director"
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .InitialFileName = CurDir ' OR ActiveWorkbook.Path OR Set a Const at top of file
        If .Show = -1 Then
            getDirectory = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            End 'Exit Subroutine and Execution Call Stack
        End If
    End With
End Function
```